# New to Linux. Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 with AMD GeForce R9 200

Tags: 14.04, gnome, amd-graphics

How do I find out if my graphics card has the correct drivers? Should I install other drivers? How do I make permanent screen adjustments?
Thank you

EDIT 1: OUTPUT OF lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 226c
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

I have typed 'gnome-shell --version' into terminal and got 'GNOME Shell 3.10.4' back. Don't know how to check that specific version number you requested?

EDIT 2:

[Screenshot of Additional Drivers Recomendations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEWRa.png)

Maybe one of those are perfect to choose. Which one is better?

EDIT 3: OUTPUT OF uname -a

```
Linux username-desktop 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: And also which 14.04 version is that? Is it 14.04.5?

Comment: I am not asking about Gnome Shell version. It is not relevant at all. What does `uname -a` show?

Comment: It looks like you are using an outdated `wily` HWE stack. You can install `fglrx` drivers by `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`. But the stack is unsupported.

Comment: Ok, does the stack being unsupported make it not worth it maybe? Then I stick to what is currently installed? Also, do you know how I can get my TV's display properties to stay after reboot? I used xrandr to set everything just right because it was rather messed up. But not one piece of advice Ive tried to follow can help me get it permanently.

Comment: It is better to update to the new `xenial` stack. You can search the web how to update HWE Stack.

Comment: Thank you for answering me so far. I have upgraded to xenial stack and I have tried a few times now to install the proprietary drivers. Whenever I reboot the screen just flashes black after POST. As if the screen is picked up again and again but not configuring well. Every time I need to go into recoevery mode, use the root shell and remove the drivers before I reboot again and everything is fine then. Have tried a few different methods with no luck. Please help, what can I do?

Comment: After you upgraded to xenial stack, proprietary drivers will not install.